# How to write this as a function

Tags: jquery

I'm sort of new to jquery and I have a toggle type jquery piece written below. Just wondering what would be a better way to write this so it's reusable.

It works like this.
Basically click on one of the radio amount options (they have the class 'nOther') then the other Amount text box is disabled. But click on the other amount radio and the textbox is enabled.

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='giftType'][value='Other']").click(function(){
        $("input[type='text'][name='otherAmount']").removeAttr('disabled');
});
$("input[type='radio'][name='giftType'][class='nOther']").click(function(){
        $("input[type='text'][name='otherAmount']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Clearly there is a better way to write this so i can reuse it

Something like function('value', 'class'){
...
}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `enabled` is not a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: ok, good to know. I can just take out the enabled lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('input[name="giftType"]').click(function(){
  $('input[name="otherAmount"]').attr('disabled',($(this).val() != 'Other'))
});
```

This checks the group of radio buttons with the name "giftType" and if the one with the value of "Other" is selected, the text box with the name "otherAmount" is disabled, else it's not disabled. Here's a quick **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQtFB/)** to test.

*Updated the backwards condition check (== to !=)*

Comment: works great except it worked backwards so I made the adjustment != 'Other' instead

Comment: +1 for using correct quote order. Note, however, that it is preferred to use `.prop` instead of `.attr` in this case in versions of jquery >= 1.6, however due to an `attrhook`, it works properly. The only version of jquery this code will not work in is 1.6.0

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, the use of attr was intentional however I should have explained that further.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with simple selector.

```
$("input[name='giftType']").click(function(){
    $("input[name='otherAmount']").prop('disabled', ($(this).val() != 'Other'));
});
```

Note: I am using `prop` method to enable/disable the textbox which is the recommended way of setting properties of elements.

Answer (score 0):

A few general pointers first:

1. jQuery attribute selectors are among the slowest, so try and use tagname, class and ids where possible.
2. Enabled isn't a valid attribute as any non-disabled element is by default enabled. If you want to check for enabled-ness later in your code you can do $("input:not([disabled])")
3. You could make the below more efficient if you can specify a containing element too, so you'd start with $("#myContainerId").find("input[type='radio']")
4. Wrapping it in a function isn't necessarily a better way to write it. Depending on how complex the code on your site gets there are a variety of ways of organising your code to keep it uncluttered. But in general, if any bit of code gets called more than once per page it should be in a function.
5. I have however wrapped your code in a jquery anonymous function wrapper, which delays the code running until after the DOM has loaded (and has the added benefit (due to everything being wrapped in the function's scope) of not adding any global variables to the DOM

f

```
$(function() {
   var otherAmountInputs = $("input[type='text'][name='otherAmount']"); //cache this expensive query
  $("input[type='radio']")
   .filter("[name='giftType'][value='Other']").click(function(){
        otherAmountInputs.removeAttr('disabled');
   })
   .end()
   .filter(".nOther[name='giftType']").click(function(){
        otherAmountInputs.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   });
});
```